# How exactly do the shortcut operators work in python?

Tags: python

I started learning python and while i was checking some of the examples about shortcut operators I ran into this one

```
a = 6
b = 3
a /= 2 * b
print(a)
```

which print 1.0 as the result which i'm sure is wrong because it's supposed to be the simplified version of:

```
a = a / 2 * b
```

which gives 9.0 as the result and I think makes more sense acording to the order

Comment: It is:  a = a / (whole right side)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a /= <anything here>` computes all of the `<anything here>` *first*, and then does the division and assignment. So in your example, it is equivalent to `a = a / (2 * b)` (note parentheses).

Answer (score 3):

Think about how the order of operations works:

```
a /= c
```

Is equivalent to

```
a = a / c
```

In a similar line,

```
a /= 2 * b
```

Is tantamount to

```
a = a / (2 * b)
```

Which equates to `6 / (2 * 3)` which indeed equals 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
a /= 2 * b
```

is in other words `a = a / ( 2 * b)`

Answer (score 1):

This

```
a /= 2 * b
```

corresponds to

```
a = a / (2 * b)
```

and not to

```
a / 2 * b
```